# Joomla Extensions MySQL state column

Tags: extensions, database

I noticed that the last column `state` in the table `#__extensions` always has a value `0`. Can you tell me what the purpose of this column is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This column is used to determine whether an extension is installed or discovered.

The following values define the state:

- `0` = *Installed*
- `-1` = *Discovered*

I'm not 100% sure if there are any other states. If so, maybe someone else could shed some light.

Comment: I tried updating this cell, setting a value `1`. As a result, the component disappeared from the extension manager search, as if it was not installed, however I could access its view. Then I set `0`, and the component appeared again.